# How to set up two desktop shortcuts to Outlook webmail when you have more than one Outlook account (e.g. Work, Personal)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, webmail

The company I work for gives me an Outlook account on their domain but my personal email is now hosted at Outlook as well.  I'd like to have separate desktop shortcuts for Outlook webmail, one for each account, but the browser always directs me to the personal account's SSO login, even when this is the URL: `https://outlook.office.com/mail/`

How to set these shortcuts up?

EDIT:

I opened up Firefox (no browsing history) and typed `https:\\outlook.office.com\mail` and was brought to a Microsoft logon dialog offering me a *choice* of my work account or my personal account.  I chose the work account, provided the password, and responded to the two-factor authentication with the numeric code texted to my phone and submitted the form.  I was taken to the Outlook365 SSO logon page for my *personal* account at foobardomainhosting.com !

Comment: Try this article   https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm ......    /profile <profilename> Loads the specified profile. If your profile name contains a space, enclose the profile name in quotation marks (“).

Comment: Should work if you type: https://outlook.office.com/mail/user@domain.ext. It will still login using the same account, but if one account has full access to the other account, it will work. If not, then use 2 browsers or 2 profiles. Chome can start with a parameter to choose what profile you want to launch.

Comment: @John not about outlook client, but webmail.

Comment: I looked up Outlook Web Mail and the profile setting was there. @Tim please let us know.

Comment: This URL still brings me to the wrong account: `https://outlook.office.chrome/mail/myname@workemaildomain.com` . Chrome launches my personal email SSO login page. So I will need to create two different *Chrome* profiles?

Comment: @John, the trouble is that I don't know what you are referring to by "there". At the first link?

Comment: @Tim For Outlook on the web, maybe used Chome shortcut for one and Edge shortcut for the other. Or try creating a Chrome shortcut for your personal usng the incognito switch then pointed to the URL. These are just suggestions to consider and research further to verify whether or not any would suffice.

Comment: If the webmail Profile setting did not work (I was not certain), then I don't know for Outlook itself. Others have pointed to browser shortcuts.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle:  I don't understand why Chrome is converting this URL `https://outlook.office.com/mail` to `sso.foobardomainhosting.com/?app=o365<snip>`.  Is it Chrome that is doing that?

Comment: I believe it's going to be the URL https://autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com setup as a Intranet trusted site zone on your computer, and then your Azure AD configuration that is doing that as described here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start. You might have Group Policies set doing that too.  But if you have that setup, once it reaches the MS SSO URL, it might do it dynamically.  Once you sign in, it remembers previous logins based on the defined PRT refshesh token controls for sessions and such too with using MFA.

Comment: I get around it using incognito mode in my Azure AD using Azure AD Connect to sync hybrid config so those are my ideas and thoughts.